# Variable not available outside FOR loop

Tags: php, variables, date, for-loop

I need to get the first and last date of the previous week. I use the code below and it works fine UNTIL I try to read the variable outside of the loop.

```
<?php
$current_week = date(W);
$previous_week = $current_week - 1;
$year = date(o);
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++) {
  $temp = array ($day => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$previous_week.$day)) . '   00:00:00');
  $firstday = $temp[1];
  // echo here works fine
  echo $firstday;
}

// echo here doesnt work anymore
echo $firstday;
?>
```

I really have no idea why this is not working. I've read through the PHP docs and everything tells me it should work.. I'm no wizz at all and I'm really confused now. Can anybody shine some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$firstDay is being reused and overwritten:

```
<?php
$current_week = date(W);
$previous_week = $current_week - 1;
$year = date(o);
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++) {
  $temp = array ($day => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$previous_week.$day)) . '   00:00:00');
  $firstday = $temp[1];
  // echo here works fine
  echo "Inloop - ".$firstday."\n";
}

// echo here doesnt work anymore
echo "After loop - ".$firstday."\n";
?>

Results:
Inloop - 2011-09-12   00:00:00
Inloop - 
Inloop - 
Inloop - 
Inloop - 
Inloop - 
Inloop - 
After loop -
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solving the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `$firstday` variabile in following iterations of the loop, so at the end it contains `null`.

If you turn on error reporting you'll see the notices generate from iterations with `$i > 1`, when accessing `$temp[1]`

You should **always** turn on error reporting when developing and when learning, and you should (or better must) solve all warning before releasing your code.

Here are the warning in your script with [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) set to `E_ALL`:

```
> php /tmp/foo.php 2>&1 | grep Notice
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant W - assumed 'W' in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 3
Notice: Use of undefined constant W - assumed 'W' in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant o - assumed 'o' in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 5
Notice: Use of undefined constant o - assumed 'o' in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 5
2011-09-12   00:00:00PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /private/tmp/foo.php on line 8
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solving the problem :)

Comment: @SjaakdeVries see my update to the answer and apply my suggestion in order to learn from your errors.